How can I combine invisible/transparent more effective in my beamer presentation?
In line with this TED Talk I'd like the subject of my sheet to appear on the following way:

invisible at start
visible when it is shown
transparant when the next subject is shown
everything should be visible when handout mode is used

The following code satisfies the conditions. However, it feels ineffective.
Is there a way to use some \alternativepause to reach it?
\documentclass{beamer}          

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

      \uncover<1>{ 
                First subject
       }
    
\pause
    
      \uncover<2>{ 
            \invisible<1|handout:0>{
                Second subject
            }
       }
       
\pause     
       
      \uncover<3>{ 
            \invisible<1-2|handout:0>{
                Third subject 
            }
       }
       
\pause     
       
      \uncover<4>{ 
            \invisible<1-3|handout:0>{
                Fourth subject
            }
       }
       
\end{frame}

\end{document}


You can separately set the opacity for still covered and again covered items:
\documentclass[
%  handout
]{beamer}          

\setbeamercovered{%
  still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause
\uncover<+>{First subject}

\uncover<+>{Second subject} 

\uncover<+>{Third subject}    

\uncover<+>{Fourth subject}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



That's way better. Less work ánd I can add a subject in between without having to do the whole ting over. Thanks. I'll try if it doesn't conflict with any other option of beamer, but I think this is a satisfying answer.

@KenAdams You're welcome!



How can I extend the period of showing to two overlays instead of one?


Is it possible two reach the initial (so, with one overlay showing) goals within itemize? Somethink like \begin{itemize}[<+->] (so, without having to customize each item?



@KenAdams If you have a new question, please ask a new question

I will! Thank you.
